# TypeError: Cannot read property 'brl' of undefined [DiscordJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando fazer uma função para meu bot de discord que faz um request em uma api de criptomoedas, está funcionando normalmente caso eu coloque na api o nome da criptomoeda manualmente, porém eu gostaria de usar um args.join pra fazer com que o request seja feito através do próprio discord, mas ele da o seguinte erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'brl' of undefined.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const axios = require('axios')
const client = new Discord.Client()


module.exports = class extends Command {
    constructor(...args){
        super(...args, {
            aliases: ['eth']

        })
        
    }

    async run(message, args) {

        let cripto = args.join(" ").toLowerCase();
        let getCotacaoBTC = async () => {
            let response = await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${cripto}&vs_currencies=brl,usd&include_24hr_change=true`)
        
        Cotacao = response.data;
        return console.log(Cotacao)
    }   

        console.log("Criptomoeda: " + cripto)
        let Cotacao;
        let cotacaoBTC = await getCotacaoBTC();
        let brl = Cotacao.cripto.brl;
        let usd = Cotacao.cripto.usd;
        let variation = Cotacao.ethereum.brl_24h_change;
        let formatado = brl.toLocaleString('pt-br', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'})
        let formatadoUSD = usd.toLocaleString('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})
        function criptoF() {


        if(variation > 0) {
            let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${cripto}`.toUpperCase())
                .setColor("GRAY")
                .addFields(
                    { name: `Cotação Atual BRL`, value: `:flag_br: ${formatadoUSD}`, inline: true},
                    { name: `Cotação Atual USD`, value: `:flag_us: ${formatadoUSD}`},
                    { name: `Variação`, value: `:chart_with_upwards_trend: +${variation.toFixed(2)}%`}
                )
                .setThumbnail(`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Ethereum_logo_2014.svg/628px-Ethereum_logo_2014.svg.png`)
            message.channel.send(embed1)
        }else if(variation < 0){
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${cripto}`.toUpperCase())
                .setColor("GRAY")
                .addFields(
                    { name: `Cotação Atual BRL`, value: `:flag_br: ${formatado}`, inline: true},
                    { name: `Cotação Atual USD`, value: `:flag_us: ${formatadoUSD}`},
                    { name: `Variação`, value: `:chart_with_downwards_trend: ${variation.toFixed(2)}%`}
                )
                .setThumbnail(`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Ethereum_logo_2014.svg/628px-Ethereum_logo_2014.svg.png`)
                channel1.send(embed)
            }
        }
        criptoF()
        

    }
```

Comment: Logo abaixo de `console.log("Criptomoeda")` você declara uma variável `Cotacao` e ela é nula, quando chega no `let brl = Cotacao.cripto.brl` vai dar erro pois Cotacao não tem nenhum valor

Comment: Acabei de fazer essas alterações no código e ainda da o mesmo erro, o que eu estou achando estranho é que estou recebendo as informações no console mas na hora de requistar brl ou qualquer coisa dentro da API da undefined.

Comment: pra te ajudar a perfila, você pode espalhar alguns console.log(qualquer váriavel), o node js vai imprimir uma "arvore", mostrando as propriedades do objeto que você fizer isto, isto vai te ajudar a além descobrir se esse "cotacao.cripto.brl" realmente existe por exemplo, descobrir todos as propriedade de cotacao.cripto, com um simples console.log(cotacao.cripto)